# Php wont execute

Tags: php, apache

When I create file index.php in directory /public/ my source code

```
<html>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOARCHIVE">
<head><NOFOLLOW><noindex>
<?php echo '123' ?>
</NOINDEX></NOFOLLOW>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

from browser looks like

```
<html>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOARCHIVE">
<head><NOFOLLOW><noindex>
123
</NOINDEX></NOFOLLOW>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

but if I create folder (no matter where) and place file index.php into it when source code become

```
<html>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOARCHIVE">
<head><NOFOLLOW><noindex>
```

if I make some correction in this file, source code stay the same, not changed in browser view.

Why I cant create and run php code where I want, except /public/ folder?

Comment: what does the error logs say?

Comment: It looks like your Apache configuration is not good. Could you give us more details about it ?

Comment: are you creating those dirs inside the /public/ dir?

Comment: no errors appears and no warnings in logs, yes inside /public/ dir

Comment: Have I can give more details? wich file I must show to you?

Comment: Is this on a shared web host, or are you running your own Apache server?  If it's your own, what distribution are you running?  Also, if you do an `ls -a` in the public directory, do you see a file named .htaccess?  If so, paste its contents here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the exact code you are using in both index.php files?

If so, they should both fail as there is a syntax error. You are missing the `;` at the end of the php code.

You posted: `<?php echo '123' ?>`
Should be :  `<?php echo '123'; ?>`

If that´s not the case, you could add the following to the top of index.php to make sure the errors are showing on the page:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
```

If any error appear after that, please post them back here.